# Removing zeros from a string using lotus notes @formula

Tags: lotus-notes

I have a view with a column that contains string field and i want to  remove all zeros (0) before  the first character, from left to right, different from 0 without modify then value of the field, so i have to use a formula in the column...

For example:

00120dn3  --> in the column i want to see    120dn3

000000001r  --> in the column i want to see    1r

191ds5000 --> in the column i want to see    191ds5000

the string lenght varies....

there is someone can help me ?

i use lotus notes 6.5.6

Comment: Is this info of any help; http://www.eknori.de/2012-07-27/formula-snippet-strip-leading-zeros-from-noteid/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the @Right function as long as there is a leading "0":

```
_str := "00120dn3";
@While(@Left(_str; 1) = "0"; 
   _str := @Right(_str; "0"));
_str
```

Comment: Thank's Knut ! Your solution is better !